# Feedback on Lambdas

Tags: kotlin

I was hoping someone could provide me some feedback on better/cleaner ways to do the following:

```kotlin
    val driversToIncome = trips
        .map { trip -> 
            // associate every driver to a cost (NOT UNIQUE)
            trip.driver to trip.cost }
        .groupBy (
            // aggregate all costs that belong to a driver
            keySelector = { (driver, _) -> driver },
            valueTransform = { (_, cost) -> cost }
        )
        .map { (driver, costs) -> 
            // sum all costs for each driver
            driver to costs.sum() }
        .toMap()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```kotlin
val driversToIncome = trips
    .groupingBy { it.driver }
    .fold(0) { acc, trip -> acc + trip.cost }
```

It groups trips by driver and while grouping it sums costs per each driver separately.

Note that [groupingBy()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/grouping-by.html) does not do anything on its own, it only prepares for the grouping operation. This solution avoids creating intermediary collections, it does everything in a single loop.

Then [fold()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html) calls the provided lambda sequentially on each item belonging to the specific group. Lambda receives a result from the previous call and it provides a new result (result is called `accumulator`). As a result, it reduces a collection of items to a single item.

You can read more about this kind of transformations in documentation about [Grouping](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-grouping.html) and [Aggregation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-aggregate.html#fold-and-reduce). Also, they aren't really inventions of Kotlin. Such operations exist in other languages and data transformation tools, so you can read about it even on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)).

Comment: thank you so much! could you please explain me what fold(0) does?

Comment: also i am getting: Type inference failed: Cannot infer type parameter R in inline fun <T, K, R> Grouping<T, K>.fold

Comment: ah ok it works if i make it:   val driversToIncome = trips
        .groupingBy { trip: Trip -> trip.driver }
        .fold(0.0) { acc: Double, trip: Trip -> acc + trip.cost }

Comment: Yes, I assumed `cost` is `Int`, but if it is not then you need to modify the code a little. Still, I'm surprised that it resulted in `Cannot infer type` error for you. It should show another error. Anyway, I updated my answer to provide more information on how does it work.  I appreciate that you try to understand what all these functions do and how to use them effectively. Good thing is that these skills/knowledge could be easily used in other languages as well, because most of these functions are named and work similarly in many languages and tools.